# NSDistributedNotificationCenter and iTunes

Tags: cocoa, itunes, nsnotifications

is there a way to send notifications to iTunes so it will tell me the current song. i know it will send a notification when the song changes but i want to get the current song when my application opens up. I am trying to avoid using the scripting bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this with notifications, your only option is the Scripting Bridge or other Apple Event-related methods.

Comment: where would be a good place to start looking for other apple-event methods?

Comment: I was talking about using one of the other methods to post Apple Events apart from the Scripting Bridge. You could post raw Apple Events using the [absolutely horrible Carbon C API](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/AppleEvents.pdf) or use `NSAppleScript`, but Scripting Bridge is the easiest and recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NSAppleScript** to run a AppleScript.

Example: to get the title and the artist of the current track

```
NSAppleScript* theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                       [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"tell application \"iTunes\" to if running then\n"
                            @"    try\n"
                            @"        tell current track to return name & return & artist\n"
                            @"    end try\n"
                            @"    return \"no track\"\n"
                            @"end if\n"
                            @"return \"iTunes is not open\"\n"]];
NSDictionary *errorDict;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *resultDescriptor = [theScript executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
NSString *title_artist = [resultDescriptor stringValue];
// do something with title_artist
```

Example: to use a AppleScript file in the "Resource folder"

```
NSString *scriptPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theScriptName" ofType:@"scpt"];
NSAppleScript *theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:scriptPath] error: nil];
```

Another solution : You can use **NSTask** to run a AppleScript via osascript